# VB.Net Invoke with Control Index

Tags: vb.net, invoke

I'm facing a problem invoking a webbrowser control from a backgroundworked since it has a index "(0)" parameter, all other invokes work.
Can I have some help?
I leave below the code:

```
Dim headElement As HtmlElement = Invoke(Sub() Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0))
```

The error says:

> Expression is not a method

Could someone kindle assist?

Best regards.

Comment: Try splitting that into two lines...Invoke() is not a function that returns the value like you want. First line just dim it: `Dim headElement as HtmlElement = Nothing`. Second line assign its value: `Invoke(Sub() headElement = Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0))`

Comment: @soohoonigan : Actually [`Invoke()` _is_ a function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Invoke_System_Delegate_), however `Sub()` isn't ;). -- _"**Returns** - Object - The return value from the delegate being invoked, or null if the delegate has no return value."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Sub()` to `Function()`. Functions are used to return a value, subs just execute code but doesn't return anything.

```
Dim headElement As HtmlElement = Invoke(Function() Me.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0))
```